# Removing non existing model from ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am going to removing existing model form my application, then its works fine.

`rails d model student`

gives:

```
 invoke  active_record
 remove    db/migrate/20170803044626_create_students.rb
 remove    app/models/student.rb
 invoke    test_unit
 remove      test/models/student_test.rb
 remove      test/fixtures/students.yml
```

when I am going to remove non-exist model like

`rails d model test`

gives:

```
     invoke  active_record
     remove    db/migrate/20170803044857_create_tests.rb
     remove    app/models/test.rb
     invoke    test_unit
     remove      test/models/test_test.rb
     remove      test/fixtures/tests.yml
```

> Why is model removing? although the model does not exist.I expect an error.

Comment: you must look into rails source code for this implementation. I don't see this as a problem.

Comment: That is how it is implemented. If you run same command again and again then even it will not complain!

Comment: @AmitPatel then where is coming from `remove    db/migrate/20170803044857_create_tests.rb
     remove    app/models/test.rb
     invoke    test_unit
     remove      test/models/test_test.rb
     remove      test/fixtures/tests.yml`

Comment: It's attempting to remove those files, but of course nothing's *actually* happening b/c they don't exist. You're just seeing the console output from the attempt to find them. Is the problem that Rails is trying to do what the user asks, or that the user is asking something impossible?